# Binding jQuery to mouseover event; setting CSS property on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, mouseover

I'm writing a calendar and am pulling event information out of a database. Then, I'm doing some processing (server-side) to try and make clashing "event" DIVs will overlap sensibly on the calendar. I'm passing data back to the browser, where jQuery positions the "event" DIVs.

Because they overlap, I thought I'd get jQuery to pop each DIV to the front (by changing its CSS z-index property) on mouseover, then pop it back on mouseout.

This involved my 1st use of jQuery data binding, which works OK, but there's a problem: when I mouse over the (simple text) content within one of my "event" DIVs, jQuery treats this as though I'm mousing out of the DIV itself.

I've made another, simpler page to test jQuery's behaviour, and in that page the mouseover behaviour is as I'd expect.

Any ideas about workarounds, problems with my code or bugs would be appreciated - thanks!

Here's the code for the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var minX = 200;
        var minY = 200;

        function renderEvent(id, content){
            $('body').append('<div class="event" id="event_' + id + '">' + content + '</div>');
            return true;
        }
        function positionEvent(id, startTime, endTime, x, ofs, w){
            x += 30;
            ofs = ofs - 1;
            $('#event_' + id)
            .position({
                'my': 'left top',
                'at': 'left top',
                'of': '#time_' + startTime,
                'offset': x + ' ' + ofs
            })
            .width(w)
            .height(
                ((endTime - startTime) * 60) + (endTime - startTime - 2) - ofs
            )
            return true;
        }
        function bindEventData(id){
            var zIndex = '9' + (1000 + id);
            $('#event_' + id)
            .css('z-index', zIndex)
            .bind("mouseout", {z: zIndex}, function(e){
                $(e.target)
                    .css('z-index', e.data.z);
                    //.css('-moz-box-shadow', 'none')
                    //.css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'none')
                    //.css('box-shadow', 'none');
            });
            return true;
        }

        function bindEventEvents(){
            $('div.event').mouseover(function(e){
                $(e.target)
                    .css('z-index', '9999999');
                    //.css('-moz-box-shadow', '0px 3px 3px #999')
                    //.css('-webkit-box-shadow', '0px 3px 3px #999')
                    //.css('box-shadow', '0px 3px 3px #999');
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(
            function(){
                var json = [
                    {"id":0,"start_time":10,"end_time":16,"x":0,"ofs":0,"w":65,"content":"Event #0:<br />10:00 - 16:00"},
                    {"id":1,"start_time":10,"end_time":12,"x":26,"ofs":3,"w":65,"content":"Event #1:<br />10:00 - 12:00"},
                    {"id":2,"start_time":10,"end_time":15,"x":52,"ofs":6,"w":65,"content":"Event #2:<br />10:00 - 15:00"},
                    {"id":3,"start_time":13,"end_time":19,"x":0,"ofs":0,"w":65,"content":"Event #3:<br />13:00 - 19:00"},
                    {"id":4,"start_time":15,"end_time":18,"x":0,"ofs":0,"w":65,"content":"Event #4:<br />15:00 - 18:00"},
                    {"id":5,"start_time":16,"end_time":17,"x":0,"ofs":0,"w":65,"content":"Event #5:<br />16:00 - 17:00"},
                    {"id":6,"start_time":16,"end_time":19,"x":26,"ofs":3,"w":65,"content":"Event #6:<br />16:00 - 19:00"},
                    {"id":7,"start_time":17,"end_time":18,"x":0,"ofs":0,"w":65,"content":"Event #7:<br />17:00 - 18:00"}
                ];
                if(json.length > 0){
                    for(i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
                        oEvent = json[i];
                        id = oEvent.id;
                        startTime = oEvent.start_time;
                        endTime = oEvent.end_time;
                        x = oEvent.x;
                        w = oEvent.w;
                        ofs = oEvent.ofs;
                        content = '<span class="event_text">' + oEvent.content + '</span>';
                        r = renderEvent(id, content);
                        r = positionEvent(id, startTime, endTime, x, ofs, w);
                        r = bindEventData(id);
                    }
                    bindEventEvents();
                }
            }
        );
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .time_wrapper {
            background-color: #ccf;
            border-top: 1px solid #99c;
            width: 180px;
            min-height: 60px;
            font-size: 0.65em;
        }
        .event {
            background-color: #cfc;
            border: 1px solid #6c6;
            -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.7em;
            width: 100px;
            padding: 2px 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_9">09:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_10">10:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_11">11:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_12">12:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_13">13:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_14">14:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_15">15:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_16">16:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_17">17:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_18">18:00</div>
        <div class="time_wrapper" id="time_19">19:00</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the behavior you're seeing is happening, however, I modified it to use hover instead of mouseenter and mouseout and it works.

```
function bindEventData(id){
    var zIndex = '9' + (1000 + id);
    $('#event_' + id)
    .css('z-index', zIndex)
    .hover(function(e){
            $(this).css('z-index', '9999999');
        }, 
        function(e){
            $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
        }
    );
    return true;
}
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZxWqD/2/